Trouble with AsymptoticIntegrate and ComplexInfinity
I am currently trying to integrate the following
$$
df_{Z,+} = \int_{0}^{\beta} \frac{\sqrt{\frac{z \left((1-2 t)^2 (6 t-1)-2 t z\right)}{t (2 t-1)^3 \left(4 t^2-2 t+z\right)}}}{4 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{t z \left(\frac{2 z}{(1-2 t)^2}-6\right)+z}} dt
$$
where $0<\beta<1/2$, $z>1/4$, and the output of the integrated $z\to+\infty$ as $t\to0^{+}$ and $t\to1/2^{-}$. I'm trying to remedy this by performing the following for asymptotic integrations
I1[t_,z_]:= AsymptoticIntegrate[dHplus[t,z],t,t -> 0,Assumptions -> {Element[t,PositiveReals],0<t<=1/4,Element[z,PositiveReals],z>=1/4}]

I2[t_,z_]:= AsymptoticIntegrate[dHplus[t,z],t,t -> 1/2,Assumptions -> {Element[t,PositiveReals],1/4<=t<1/2,Element[z,PositiveReals],z>=1/4}]

Where ideally the final answer would be I[β,z] = I2[β,z] - I1[0,z]. The problem is that Mathematica keeps giving the following error for the I1 integral:
Infinity: Indeterminate expression ComplexInfinity+ComplexInfinity encountered

I tried to remedy this by putting Abs[] around the t variable before integrating like so
I1[t_,z_]:= AsymptoticIntegrate[dHplus[Abs[t],z],t,t -> 0,Assumptions -> {Element[t,PositiveReals],0<t<=1/4,Element[z,PositiveReals],z>=1/4}]

However, I still get the same errors. I'm fairly novice with Mathematica and I am pretty far from knowing what the best practices are for this sort of thing. Any suggestions as to how to get a complete expression for I[β,z] would be greatly appreciated.
Code for integrand function
Sqrt[(z ((1-2 t)^2 (-1+6 t)-2 t z))/(t (-1+2 t)^3 (-2 t+4 t^2+z))]/(4 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[z+t z (-6+(2 z)/(1-2 t)^2)])


A slight modification of your code succeeds in 14.1 on Windows :
AsymptoticIntegrate[Sqrt[(z ((1 - 2 t)^2 (-1 + 6 t) - 2 t z))/
(t (-1 + 2 t)^3 (-2 t +  4 t^2 + z))]/
(4 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[ z + t z (-6 + (2 z)/(1 - 2 t)^2)]), t, t -> 0, 
Assumptions -> z > 1/4 && t > 0]


Sqrt[t]/(2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[z])

AsymptoticIntegrate[ Sqrt[(z ((1 - 2 t)^2 (-1 + 6 t) - 2 t z))/
(t (-1 + 2 t)^3 (-2 t + 4 t^2 + z))]/
(4 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[z + t z (-6 + (2 z)/(1 - 2 t)^2)]), t, t -> 1/2, 
Assumptions -> z > 1/4 && t > 0 && t < 1/2]


-(((-1)^( 3/4 + Floor[( 2 \[Pi] -  Arg[-I + 2 I t + 2 I z + Sqrt[-1 + 4 z] - 2 t Sqrt[-1 + 4 z]])/( 2 \[Pi])]) Sqrt[I z] Sqrt[1/(1 - 2 z + I Sqrt[-1 + 4 z])] EllipticK[1 - (2 I Sqrt[-1 + 4 z])/(1 - 2 z + I Sqrt[-1 + 4 z])])/( 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[z]))

Both asymptotics are in accordance with
Reduce[FunctionDomain[Sqrt[(z ((1 - 2 t)^2 (-1 + 6 t) - 2 t z))/(t (-1 + 2 t)^3 (-2 t + 
     4 t^2 + z))]/(4 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[
  z + t z (-6 + (2 z)/(1 - 2 t)^2)]), t], t, Reals]


(z < 0 &&  1/2 < t < 1/4 + 1/4 Sqrt[1 - 4 z]) || (0 < z <= 1/ 4 && (0 < t < 1/4 - 1/4 Sqrt[1 - 4 z] ||  1/4 + 1/4 Sqrt[1 - 4 z] < t < 1/2)) || (z > 1/4 && 0 < t < 1/2)

Addition. If you are interested in the asymtotic of the definite integral, then
AsymptoticIntegrate[Sqrt[(z ((1 - 2 t)^2 (-1 + 6 t) - 2 t z))/
(t (-1 + 2 t)^3 (-2 t + 4 t^2 + z))]/
(4 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[z + t z (-6 + (2 z)/(1 - 2 t)^2)]), {t, 0, b}, 
 z -> \[Infinity], Assumptions -> b > 0 && b < 1/2]


(Sqrt[z^2] ArcSin[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[b]])/(4 z^(3/2))

does the work.

The latter asymptotic seems doubtful in view of -(((-1)^(3/4 +            Floor[(2 \[Pi] -                Arg[-I + 2 I t + 2 I z + Sqrt[-1 + 4 z] -                  2 t Sqrt[-1 + 4 z]])/(2 \[Pi])]) Sqrt[I z] Sqrt[         1/(1 - 2 z + I Sqrt[-1 + 4 z])] EllipticK[         1 - (2 I Sqrt[-1 + 4 z])/(1 - 2 z +              I Sqrt[-1 + 4 z])])/(2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[z])) /. {z -> 1/2,     t -> 0.49} // N which results in 0.327757 - 0.327757 I despite the positivity of the integrand.

No shade of doubt in view of -(((-1)^(3/4 +            Floor[(2 \[Pi] -                Arg[-I + 2 I t + 2 I z + Sqrt[-1 + 4 z] -                  2 t Sqrt[-1 + 4 z]])/(2 \[Pi])]) Sqrt[I z] Sqrt[         1/(1 - 2 z + I Sqrt[-1 + 4 z])] EllipticK[         1 - (2 I Sqrt[-1 + 4 z])/(1 - 2 z +              I Sqrt[-1 + 4 z])])/(2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[z])) /. {z -> 1/2,     t -> 0.499999} // N which results in 0.327757 - 0.327757 I. An antiderivative is defined up to a constant which may be a complex number.
